# Will memcached improve performance with WP Super Cache already running?

Tags: database, optimization, memory, plugin-wp-supercache

I'm working on a WordPress site that is expected to host up to 1000 concurrent users, so I'm exploring ways to make it run as fast as possible. I've heard that memcached helps WordPress sites load faster, but when I read what it does, it seems to have areas of overlap with WP Super Cache, especially if you use it in Expert Mode (where everything is cached in HTML and routed at the .htaccess level, so there are no database queries).

Am I right on this? Or does memcached cover areas where WP Super Cache doesn't to give performance improvements?

Comment: i would recommend adding an object cache if you don't have one, however, WP Super cache is a 3rd party plugin and not in the scope of this site. For WP Super cache questions you should contact their support routes.

Answer (score 0):

In the most simple terms, memcached/redis is for caching things like options and database values.

WP Super Cache is meant for serving static HTML files, instead of loading PHP, but with that said, it will still have to run PHP code to generate those files.

So yes, if you have the option of using memcached or redis, it's always a good idea to enable it as your site will benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

memcached/redis for sure cover areas where WP Super Cache does nothing at all so to speak, lets get to the point.

WP Super Cache caching takes care of caching static resources (images, HTML, CSS and JS files) and browser caching manages the same resources within the browser, memcached/redis object caching is devoted to your database.

The aim of object caching is to cache query results from your database.

Memcached is solely relying on RAM, it doesn’t require too many CPU resources, so make sure you're good.